# Calculating Sum of Two character arrays representing floating point numbers without any helper functions

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I need a function that has the following format

```
public char[] CalculateSum(char[] first,char[] second)
{

}
```

**The big restriction for this is it it must use basic operations and no predefined functions/methods or parsing.**

Sample Invocation

```
char[] first = ['2','3','.','4','5'];
char[] second = ['2','.','5'];

char[] result = CalculateSum(first,second);
Console.Write(result) --> Will print "25.95"
```

Comment: int before the point, float after the point, adding them gives result. You need to multiply rightmost int with 1, left one with 10, left one with 100, .... but the floating part needs multiplication by 0.1 , right one needs 0.01 right one 0.001. then you add them. then do same thing for second parameter then sum them

Comment: I guess it can be easier if you change the input arrays to have the same length. So in your example, the second array would be changed to be: ['0', '2', '.', '5', '0'].
Doing that you just need to a loop iterating through both arrays and doing the calculation.

Comment: @usr threadstarter seems to be an OK user, give him some credit!

Comment: @usr thats a shame, I think this quest is more about applied algorithms than about homework, makes it an interesting one imo

Comment: @usr This is not a homework question, rather it is a popular interview question asked by large reputable shops like Amazon and Google.

Comment: @TheJediCowboy Yeah it looks like some ACM quickie, so I really dont get why delete it. Live and let live!